# How can I change the background color with javascript?

Tags: colors, background

I would like to change the background colour from "form-group". How can I do this?

```
<div id="music">
  <form>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
     </div>
  </form>
</div>



function changeBackground(colour) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("form-group").style.backgroundColor = colour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try do it in loop, for each element in class?

```
function changeBackground(colour) {
   elems = document.getElementsByClassName("form-group");
   for (it i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
    {
       elems[i].style.backgroundColor=color;
    }
}
```

best regards